# I uploaded a chrome extension to the webstore last night and the status says published to testers but when I try to use the link I get a 404 error

Tags: google-chrome-extension, publish, browser-extension, web-publishing

This is my first extension, so sorry if this is a dumb question but I'm very confused. [Here](https://youtu.be/wDxasi84wnk) is a video of the issue. You can see on the items page that the extension is listed as published to testers. When I click on status under the build menu, for some reason its listed as both "this draft is unpublished" and "this draft is published to testers." I'm not sure what that means or if that's supposed to be that way. But when I click on the link that I expected to take me to the extension page, I get a 404 error. What am I doing wrong?

I also tried adding another email I have as a trusted tester, logging into chrome with that email, and opening the link then, but it still just gives me the 404 error.